# How to detect select onChange in a row cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a dynamic table using java script and jquery, one of my project requirement is a select box in a row cell,

From the this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045658/getting-value-from-table-tr-id-and-td-id) i am able to place a on click listener on a table row which gives me id of table row and cell(tr and td) but i am not able to detect select onchange i have also tried "[jQuery get value of select onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange)" but it is also not working in my case!!

My problem is

> How to detect select on Change in a row cell as i have to update that
>   changed data in database?

thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: show your code and create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will get everything you'll need for your database (value selected, cell and row it was selected in)... something like:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3532cjsf/1/)

```
$("td select").on("change", function() {
    var value = this.value;
    var $cell = $(this).parent();
    var $row = $cell.parent();
    alert("Selected ["+value+"] in cell ["+$cell.index()+"] of row ["+$row.index()+"]");
});
```

Comment: your code has solved my problem,thank you vary much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change','td',function(){
  //Do your abacadabra!
});
```